# How to deal turn turbulent water flow into streamline water flow in Taps

Tags: water, faucet, pipe

I have so many water taps at home.

But two of the taps water flow is **turbulent** and rest of the taps have **streamline** water flow

[Check out Turbulent water flow Tap 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1II-0b2lMect2qkIud51Bn-v1mRdDGXx5/view)

[Check out Turbulent water flow Tap 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U9mlz30PBO8ocjgXalj7eP-Solob0U-V/view)

[Check out Streamline water flow](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KXP4qO8WG3cn7743oIrtiXHpLo16iOen/view)

I have checked there are no clogs in the pipe.

Is it because of low water pressure ?

Or any ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: how did you check for No Clogs in the pipe ?

Comment: I just cleaned the aerator and tap. Do you mean to say I should clean the connecting pipe or else I should be able to run the sink snake and clean inside the pipe ?

Comment: You have no idea what flow regime the water actually has *in the pipes*.  Whether flow is laminar or turbulent (or transitional) depends on the Reynolds number, a function of density, velocity, kinematic viscosity, and diameter.

Comment: Ok so what needs to be done to fix the issue ?

Comment: Why do you consider it an issue?

Comment: Is this turbulent flow new/developed over time, or has it been this way since you moved in?

Comment: @keshlam - Streamlined water flow is considered normal if the water flow is turbulent then something is wrong like negative pressure inside pipe or air bubble or something not right, that's why I think

Comment: @FreeMan - The turbulent flow is not new that's the way since it's inception

Comment: That looks to me like ordinary water flow from a less than perfectly circular pipe outlet, possibly aided and abetted by irregularity inside the pipe. I honestly don't see why you consider this a significant problem.

Comment: Basically the water is splashing a bit and flow of water is less in one of the taps because of this turbulent water flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most taps have screens at the end of the faucet.  They get clogged up.

Remove the end of of faucet by unscrewing, might need pliers so use a soft cloth or similar, and clean.

Usually vinegar or store bought calcium/lime cleaner.

Comment: The tap 1 had aerator , I cleaned the tap ( Faucet ) and aerator.. I'm getting the turbulent flow even after cleaning also.